# C program: Random matrix generator only saves last row (help appreciated!)

Tags: c, matrix

I am creating a program that manipulates a matrix.
Part of the program is that I need to generate a matrix with random inputs.

However, upon generating the matrix and printing each value of the matrix to double-check that the randomized numbers are being stored properly, **the matrix seems to only be storing the last row of numbers, and then duplicating it.**

Here is a screenshot to explain what I am referring to:
[image: Here is a screenshot to explain what I am referring to:]

**You can see that it creates the matrix [[3,6][7,5]] But it only shows it sores as [[7,5][7,5]]**

And here is my code that isolates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, m, n, row, col;
  int sum = 0, row_i=0, col_i=0;

  int matrix[m][n];
  int row_m[m];

  printf("Enter m\n");
  scanf("%d", &m);

  printf("Enter n\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
      matrix[i][j] = rand()%10;
      printf("%d  ",matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("%d\n", matrix[0][0]);
  printf("%d\n", matrix[0][1]);
  printf("%d\n", matrix[1][0]);
  printf("%d\n", matrix[1][1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the arrays *after* you get `m` and `n` from the user.

Comment: @Jessica Donley; These declarations   int matrix[m][n];
  int row_m[m]; are invalid because the variables m and n are not initialized.

Comment: @Barmar You fixed it! Lol I have a long ways to learn, but thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  int matrix[m][n];
  int row_m[m];

  printf("Enter m\n");
  scanf("%d", &m);

  printf("Enter n\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
```

use

```
  printf("Enter m\n");
  scanf("%d", &m);

  printf("Enter n\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int matrix[m][n];
  int row_m[m];
```

to define your `matrix` and `row_m` **after** you got the values of `m`, `n`.